# Yii2: How to send data from one page to another?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

On **roompage.php** page I have data like :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' =>['site/checkout'],'method' => 'POST']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'room_type')->hiddenInput(['value'=>$data->room_type])->label(false); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'rate')->hiddenInput(['value'=>$data->rate])->label(false); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('CHECKOUT', ['class' => 'button btn btn-default']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I need to pass this data to `checkout.php` page How to do this? Can I send data through URL ? If yes then how to do this or any other way to do the same?

```
public function actionCheckout()
    {      
        $model = new CreateBookings();
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
    if(isset($data['DynamicModel'])) 
    {
    $room_type = $data['DynamicModel']['room_type']; 
    }
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect('confirmation');
        } 
        else 
        {
            return $this->render('checkout', [
            'model' => $model,'room_type' => $room_type]);
        }
    }

public function actionRoompage($room_id)
    {   $model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['room_type','rate']);
        $searchModel = new RoomTypesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $data = RoomTypes::find()->where(['room_id' => $room_id])->one();
        return $this->render('roompage', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
    }
```

Need to pass data from `actionRoompage()` to `actionCheckout()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `POST` request to send some data to another page in this case. In `actionCheckout` you are already ready to get `POST` data and load it ot the model `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`

You also need to create form in your view `roompage.php`
For example, in your `actionRoompage` also create `$model = new CreateBookings();`

And than  in view display inputs(you can make them hidden):

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'checkout-form']); ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'quantity') ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
<?php echo Html::submitButton(Yii::t('frontend', 'Login'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: can you suggest what to write in `actionCheckout` to get POST data

Comment: You already use this `POST` data, see `$data = Yii::$app->request->post();`

Also you use them to load model attributest, 
`$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`